# Android Studio - Constraint Layout inside Fragment not aligned properly

Tags: android, layout, constraints, alignment, fragment

I am trying to use the Constraint Layout inside a Fragment for my application. The problem, as you can see from the pictures below, is that no matter what I do, the layout seems to be starting halfway through the screen.
This is my code for **fragment_progress.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/app_purple"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    tools:context=".ProgressFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text="Your Progress"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Current Goal: "
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_title" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_header2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fg_progress_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_goalprogress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Goal Progress:"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_header" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_points"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_goalprogress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_points2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Points"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fg_progress_points"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_goalprogress" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_bar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_points" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_awardstitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Awards Unlocked:"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_bar" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_award1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_awardstitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_badgestitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Badges Obtained:"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_award1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_badge1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_badgestitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_whotitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="The World Health Organization Recommends:"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_badge1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_whoheader1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Know that it is okay to feel how you are feeling."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_whotitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_whocontent1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="It is normal during this crazy time to experience feelings of sadness, anger frustration, stress, or all of the above. You are allowed to feel this way and to communicate with others how you are feeling."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_whoheader1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_whoheader2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Maintain a routine."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_whocontent1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_whocontent2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Start your day at about the same time each day. Set a goal for coursework to be completed for each morning and afternoon. Maintain adequate nutrition by eating three healthy meals per day. Try to get in at least one physical activity each day."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_whoheader2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_whoheader3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Practice good sleep hygiene."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_whocontent2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_whocontent3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Maintain a consistent sleep schedule. The goal should be 7-9 hours per night. Limit screen time in the evening, and avoid caffeine starting in the afternoon."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_whoheader3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_whoheader4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Connect with others."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_whocontent3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_whocontent4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="It is easy to quickly feel lonely and secluded from others during this stay-at-home period. Make an effort to stay socially connected by engaging in regular video or phone calls with friends and family."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_whoheader4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_whoheader5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Take a break."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_whocontent4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_whocontent5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="Take time for yourself each day. Step away from the news and from your coursework to do something you enjoy and that you find relaxing or rejuvenating."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_whoheader5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fg_progress_fblink"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="(https://www.facebook.com/coronavirus_info/core_tips)"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fg_progress_whocontent5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It used to contain a FrameLayout and a ScrollView, but I removed them to simplify the code because they were not helping. These are two pictures of how the phone screen should look like and how it really looks:
(Please ignore the Action Bar and the Bottom Navigation Menu)

Android Studio
[image: Android Studio]

Phone
[image: Phone]

I've literally tried everything, from switching `match_parent` to `wrap_content`, setting margins on the elements or the layout itself, changing the gravity, etc. The only thing that worked is setting a negative bottom margin of **-800dp** to the Constraint Layout, but that breaks the scrolling functionality, and adding a ScrollView does not help. I have no idea why this is happening. I just need the first TextView to go to the top of the screen. Everything else is properly constrained so they'll follow.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both images have nothing in similar, what do you really want to achieve from here?

Comment: Isn't the android:layout_marginTop="100dp" in the first TextView causing the margin?

Comment: No, it's not the android:layout_marginTop="100dp". I want the app on the phone (image 2) to be displayed like the screenshot from Android Studio (image 1). But, half of the stuff I've got on the layout isn't even displayed when I run the app, it starts from "Know that it's okay to feel how you're feeling" as you can see from the second image, while it should be starting from the top...
I've tried removing the margin, but it appears that it has nothing to do with it

Comment: oh you mean it's a problem with the app at runtime, when you run it you don't see {"Goal progress" ,"awards unlocked", "badges obtained", "your progress"}, it just starts directly with the paragraph ?

Comment: Exactly! I apologize if it was unclear, didn't really know how to describe it since English isn't my first language. But yeah, that's what happens

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not with the XML code of the fragment but with the host activity layout file.
Since you are hosting the fragments for the bottom navigation in an activity, if you check the XML code it might be the case that you would find that it has `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` this code in the parent view of the activity.
Remove the padding and it works fine.